# How can i Copy Paste from Word to Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, syntax-error

[those are whitespaces that i need to remove and moreover broken characters like small ‘n’ or big ‘o’ replaced the normal chars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iop0k.jpg)

What i did is manually removing  the gibrish white spaces and changing the random characters  back to normal which consumes too much time

Comment: Don't write code in Word.

Comment: It's actually very smart suggesting not to use Word for coding. Word will for example automatically capitalize characters after a newline or after the end of a sentence. This automatic capitalization will introduce syntax errors in your code (not to talk about indentation, which is critical in python). Use a text editor that uses plain text and not rich text. Windows comes with Notepad, but I strongly suggest using something better, like Notepad++ or any other proper coding text editor/IDE. If you want a bit of humor check why [Word is the best IDE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X34ZmkeZDos)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the text into a plain text editor like notepad to normalize the text, then copy from there into PyCharm. If there are artifacts left over, use find and replace to weed them out.

Comment: Why would Notepad do a better job of this than PyCharm?